# Loop by Quantity from two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one shows buys and the other shows sell. I need to pull sale date for each buy lot. Sometimes, the buy is sold in different sale lots, I need to be able to split shares for that(or if not possible, no need to split shares, just pull the selldate). This is what I have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AAA','AAA', 'AAA','BBB','CCC'],
               'Buydate': ['2017-04-13', '2019-12-31', '2019-03-05', '2018-11-04', '2019-12-31' ],
               'Quantity': [100.00,  2000.00, 385.95, 214514.00, 63205.00]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AAA','AAA','BBB'],
               'Selldate': ['2020-01-25', '2020-10-25', '2020-12-19'],
               'Quantity': [500.00,  1985.95, 214714.00]})
```

Output is：

```
df1
 ID   |  Buydate |   Quantity
0  AAA  2017-04-13     100.00
1  AAA  2019-12-31    2000.00
2  AAA  2019-03-05     385.95
3  BBB  2018-11-04  214514.00
4  CCC  2019-12-31   63205.00

df2
    ID    Selldate   Quantity
0  AAA  2020-01-25     500.00
1  AAA  2020-10-25    1985.95
2  BBB  2020-12-19  214714.00
```

First I added cumsum column, then I plan to use a loop for df1 each group to look for df2 by ID, if share is less than the quantity of first lot in df2, I use original quantity of df1, if it's over, I need to get the remaining quantity and continue to look for the second lot of df2. I guess I need a concat function at some point.

The ideal result is:

```
    ID     Buydate   Quantity  SplitQuantity   Selldate
0  AAA  2017-04-13     100.00         100.00 2020-01-25
1  AAA  2019-03-05     385.95         385.95 2020-01-25
2  AAA  2019-12-31    2000.00         14.05  2020-01-25
3  AAA  2019-12-31    2000.00        1985.95 2020-10-25  
4  BBB  2018-11-04  214514.00      214514.00 2020-12-19
5  CCC  2019-12-31   63205.00            NaN        NaT
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second row in the output be for 'Buydate' as 2019-03-05(and corresponding calculations thereafter). As the open quantity of 400 be matched to 385.95 before matching with future buy date 2019-12-31.

Comment: You are correct. I updated it, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a little messy, but what you're asking is a little complicated, so here comes a working prototype:

```
# Sort values by date.
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='Buydate').reset_index()

# id_jumps will be used for ignoring items you already subtracted from. 
id_jump = {}
for id_ in df1['ID']:
    id_jump[id_] = 0

new_index = ['ID', 'Buydate', 'Quantity', 'SplitQuantity', 'Selldate']
new_df = []

# For all items in DF2, subtrack the quantity from items in df1 with the same ID.
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    sum_ = row['Quantity']
    
    for index2, row2 in df1[df1['ID'] == row['ID']].iterrows():
        if index2 < id_jump[row['ID']]:
            # Skip items already included from previous purchases.
            continue
        if sum_ > row2['Quantity']:
            sub = row2['Quantity']
            sum_ = sum_ - row2['Quantity']
            id_jump[row['ID']] += 1
            new_df.append(
                [row2['ID'], row2['Buydate'], row2['Quantity'], sub, row['Selldate']])
        else:
            id_jump[row['ID']] += 1
            new_df.append(
                [row2['ID'], row2['Buydate'], row2['Quantity'], sum_, row['Selldate']])
            break

df3 = pd.DataFrame(new_df, columns=new_index)

# Add missing 'CCC' row, for IDs never bought.
for id_ in df1['ID']:
    if id_jump[id_] == 0:
       df4 = pd.concat([df3, df1[df1['ID'] == id_]]).drop(columns='index').reset_index()
print(df4)

#     ID     Buydate   Quantity  SplitQuantity    Selldate
# 0  AAA  2017-04-13     100.00         100.00  2020-01-25
# 1  AAA  2019-03-05     385.95         385.95  2020-01-25
# 2  AAA  2019-12-31    2000.00          14.05  2020-01-25
# 3  AAA  2019-12-31    2000.00        1985.95  2020-10-25
# 4  BBB  2018-11-04  214514.00      214514.00  2020-12-19
# 5  CCC  2019-12-31   63205.00            NaN         NaN
```

Comment: It works！I have thought it in mind as nested loop but not able to write it down. You are the genius. Thank you!